# Outsource Mails and continue using Microsoft Exchange Groupware functions

Tags: exchange, email-server

Im runnuing a Microsoft Exchange 2007 Server for Mailing and Groupware but now I want to outsource the Mailing but still want to continue using the Groupware functions.

I want to make this transparent for the users if possible. Is there any way to use the Exchange as a mail delay so the external server is running the mails?

Comment: I often use Exchange as a mail delay.

Comment: For incoming and outgoing mails aswell?

Comment: Oh sure, it can delay anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it's not really *outsourcing* the mail. Mail is still being sent and received via Exchange. For your outbound SMTP connector, you specify a smarthost; that will be your external mail vendor.

Then you need to figure out if you want your external vendor to handle your inbound mail, which would entail setting your domain's MX record to point to their SMTP server, and configuring their server to relay everything to your Exchange server.

If you're using Outlook, you can also set up everyone with a second account (that being at the external provider), and setting that up as the default Send Provider in Outlook. Might make routing of the groupware items messy though; I've never done this and you might need to test it.

Why, exactly, are you looking to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?